# How to test a correlation?

Tags: matlab

How to test wheater there is a correlation between two parameters? I have n-dimensional parameters a and b in matlab? I would like to find the correlation parametr is there a simply function for it? Thank you

I tried:

```
C = [a b];
cov(C)
```

I got

```
0.0001    0.0029
0.0029    1.0668
```

And

```
corrcoef(C)
```

with the result

```
1.0000    0.3682
0.3682    1.0000
```

I sould look at diagonnal members - they are 1, so it is correlation?

Is that right?
[image]

1

```
1.0000   -0.3143
-0.3143    1.0000
```

2

```
1.0000    0.4248
0.4248    1.0000
```

3

```
1.0000   -0.3290
   -0.3290    1.0000
```

4

```
1.0000   -0.1397
   -0.1397    1.0000
```

5

```
1.0000   -0.1506

  -0.1506    1.0000
```

6

```
1.0000    0.3682
0.3682    1.0000
```

Comment: Did you type “MATLAB correlation” into Google? The first hit for me is the documentation page of the function you’re looking for.

Comment: I added what I tried to my question. Is it correct?

Comment: `cov` is covariance, not correlation. `corrcoef` is correct. Read the documentation for what it means. The diagonal elements are the correlation of each variable with itself—useless. The off-diagonal elements are the ones you want to look at. You have a correlation of 0.3682.

Comment: Thank you, so 0,3682 is too less number. It mean that is corelate in 36 %? It is not covariance?

Comment: Ane negative numbers mean completly not correlated?

Comment: 0 means no correlation. Negative numbers mean inverse correlation (one value goes up as the other goes down).

Comment: Thank you I got result I added to my question. What is the border of correlation coeficient where is possible to say it is correlated?